# Redirect all the headers from upstream to another location in nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-upstreams

Could you please tell me if it's possible to redirect **all** the headers in nginx from upstream /auth_gateway to /connection.
My request and nginx configuration

`curl -silent -include -X 'GET' -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJZa0hadkt5YUJuNU9oaVF6d3kxWXduNFBHYm5RSDV0aDh1ZkhOWHZiTVdrIn0' -H 'x-realy-company: google' -H 'x-realy-request-id: 12545787' https://mycooldomain.org/connection/`

New headers will be to add on the authorization service /auth_gateway, such as x-realy-privileges, x-realy-user and others.

```
location ~* ^/connection/ {
            if ($http_authorization !~ "^Bearer .{20,}"){
                return 403 "Not authorized";
            }
            auth_request /auth_gateway;
            auth_request_set $auth_status $upstream_status;
            proxy_pass http://10.xx.xx.xx:8080;
        }
        
location = /auth_gateway {
            proxy_pass http://10.xx.xx.xx:8081/authorize;
            proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
        }
```

`x-realy-user: da82fe4b-d0ef-477e-a3d1-facc78b605c7`

`x-realy-privileges: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`

`x-realy-global-roles: ROLE_OPERATOR`

`x-realy-okt-id: da82fe4b-d0ef-477e-a3d1`

These headers are extracted from the Bearer authorization token and I would like to redirect them to the /connection

Thanks and advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did it via lua module. I hope this helps someone in the future.

full code here

```
location ~* ^/connection/ {
            if ($http_authorization !~ "^Bearer .{20,}"){
                return 403 "Not authorized";
            }
            auth_request /auth_gateway;
            auth_request_set $auth_status $upstream_status;
            
            rewrite_by_lua_block {
                local res1 = ngx.location.capture("/auth_gateway", {method=ngx.HTTP_GET, args=args})
                local concat = table.concat
                for name, value in pairs(res1.header) do
                    if type(value) == "table" then
                        ngx.req.set_header(name, concat(value, ", "))
                    else
                        ngx.req.set_header(name, value)
                    end
                end
            }
            
            proxy_pass http://10.xx.xx.xx:8080;
        }
        
location = /auth_gateway {
            proxy_pass http://10.xx.xx.xx:8081/authorize;
            proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
        }
```